# How to remove values from dictionary that are not numbers in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, numbers

I have a dictionary of this type

```
d={"Key":[name,value1,value2]}
```

I need only numbers in my value's list. 
How can I remove name ?

Thak you!

Comment: You should show exactly how you're trying to use `isdigit`

Comment: Could you please explain more precisely what you want to do? It's unclear at the moment.

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann I would like to remove elements that are not numbers in my dictionary

Comment: Is value an integer or a string, e.g. `42` or `"42"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import numbers

for key, values in d.iteritems():
   d[key] = [x for x in values if isinstance(x, numbers.Number)]
```

The [numbers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/numbers.html) package is available since 2.6. Otherwise you need to check manually for any numerical type (int, float, long, complex)

`iteritems()` has been removed and is now identical to `items()` in 3.x

Answer (score 2):

If `name` is always at the start of the list, the simply `d['Key'][1:]` will suffice. Otherwise, you can use the following:

```
[i for i in d['Key'] if i.isdigit()]
```

Of course, I'm assuming that all of the items in `d['Key']` are strings. Otherwise you cannot use `isdigit()`.

Answer (score -2):

```
In [1]: d = {'k1': [1,2,3,'a','b','c'], 'k2': ['e',4.3,'f',5.2]}
In [2]: for k,v in d.iteritems():
   ...:     #This will keep only integers, but will fail on the floats since isdigit() return False on non-integers 
   ...:     d[k] = filter(lambda e: str(e).isdigit(), v)

   ...:     #On the other hand, This will be a generic solution for any numeric type
   ...:     d[k] = filter(lambda e: isinstance(e, numbers.Number), v)
   ...:
In [3]: d
Out[3]: {'k1': [1, 2, 3], 'k2': [4.3, 5.2]}
```

Comment: It works only for int numbers , there is a way to include also float?

Comment: You never said it should.
Any way, you can use the numbers package, and check if `lambda e: isinstance(e, numbers.Number)`

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.