# Remove all non-numeric symbols from dictionaries in a column with a specific condition

Tags: python, pandas, digits

I have a column in a data frame.

[image]

I would like to keep numeric values **only for rows with "amount":**, where these digits mean the payment sum.

**My ideal column output - digits remain only in the rows, where "amount" was before.** Everything else is NaN.

```
value
500
NaN
4
3
NaN
```

etc

I tried

```
test_df['value'] = test_df['value'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand = False)
```

but it converts all column values to NaN. Plus it will not differentiate columns with "amount":, so not helpful anyway.

I also tried solutions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37877744/how-to-remove-values-from-dictionary-that-are-not-numbers-in-python), but did not figure out it so far. Thanks!

UPDATED:

```
{"person": "78afa995795e4d85b5d9ceeca43f5fef", "event": "offer received", 
"value": {"offer id": "9b98b8c7a33c4b65b9aebfe6a799e6d9"}, "time": 0}
{"person": "a03223e636434f42ac4c3df47e8bac43", "event": "offer received", 
"value": {"offer id": "0b1e1539f2cc45b7b9fa7c272da2e1d7"}, "time": 0}
{"person": "e2127556f4f64592b11af22de27a7932", "event": "offer received", 
"value": {"offer id": "2906b810c7d4411798c6938adc9daaa5"}, "time": 0}
{"person": "8ec6ce2a7e7949b1bf142def7d0e0586", "event": "offer received", 
"value": {"offer id": "fafdcd668e3743c1bb461111dcafc2a4"}, "time": 0}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are dictionaries, so use [`Series.str.get`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html):

```
test_df = pd.read_pickle('col.pkl').to_frame()

test_df['value'] = test_df['value'].str.get('amount')
print (test_df)
        value
0         NaN
1         NaN
2         NaN
3         NaN
4         NaN
      ...
306529   1.59
306530   9.53
306531   3.61
306532   3.53
306533   4.05

[306534 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: Nope, it gives all NaNs :(

Comment: Series.str.get takes an int as parameter

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker - What is `print (test_df['value'].head(3).to_dict())` ?

Comment: @jezrael I'm merely quotting what is written in the link you posted https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html

Comment: @jezrael, {0: {'offer id': '9b98b8c7a33c4b65b9aebfe6a799e6d9'}, 1: {'offer id': '0b1e1539f2cc45b7b9fa7c272da2e1d7'}, 2: {'offer id': '2906b810c7d4411798c6938adc9daaa5'}}

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker - It seems some data related problem, Is possible create file by this column and share? `test_df['value'].to_pickle('col.pkl')`, because sample data working perfectly, edited answer.

Comment: @jezrael, updated the post, please take a look! Appreciate help!

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker - unfortunately I need not text data, but file with real data by pickle, so not possible use (because for me working perfectly), so please use `test_df['value'].to_pickle('col.pkl')` and share by dropbox, gdocs or similar real data for test.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H8-OiW0uVnj1l-q5wbJKLUk4J7jxjZmQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker - hmm, interesting, for me working nice, what is your pandas version? Answer was edited.

Comment: @jezrael, works! Appreciate tremendously time and efforts!

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker - It was my first answer ;) [link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63009651/revisions), for you not working in first testing?

Comment: @jezrael, ok, fair, you right. I will accept it. The syntax is cleaner too. But would like to say a huge thank you to both!

Comment: @HichamZouarhi `str.get` is defined this way the source code `if isinstance(x, dict):return x.get(i) elif len(x) > i >= -len(x):return x[i]
        return np.nan` if Series has dicts then `i` can be any hashable item. Github repo link to [`str.get`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.0.5/pandas/core/strings.py#L1837)

Answer (score 1):

if value is a dictionary you should try to get the amount key if it exists

```
test_df['value'] = test_df['value'].apply(lambda x: x.get("amount") if "amount" in x.keys() else None)
```

**EDIT**

in case they are not all dicts, ocnvert value to string and strip `{"amount" :` and `}`

```
test_df['value'] = test_df['value'].apply(lambda x: float(str(x).strip("{'amount' :").strip('}')) if "amount" in str(x) else None)
```

Comment: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal :(

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker my bad I forgot a double quote

Comment: Nope :( AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker not the best ways to do it but I think the edit should work

Comment: Still no, NameError: name 'null' is not defined

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker switched from java to python too fast and confused None to null, I've edited it